# Advanced Calculus Homework

Tags: calculus, polynomials

For real numbers $a_1, a_2, \dots , a_n$, let $p(x)= a_1 x + a_2x^2 + \dots + a_nx^n$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $$\frac{a_1}{2} + \frac{a_2}{3} + \dots + \frac{a_n}{n+1} = 0.$$ Prove that there exists $x \in (0,1)$ such that $p(x)=0$.

I realize that $a_1/2 + a_2/3 + \dots a_n/(n+1)$ would be the coefficients of the integral of $p$, since p is a polynomial and therefore integrable in R.

I tried creating another function $F$ such that $F'=p$, and then creating another function $f=p-F$. Whenever $f = 0$, then $p$ must equal $0$ as well. How can I show that F = 0 for some x in (0,1).

Comment: Polynomials are integrable on every interval.

Comment: p(x) is polynomial functions and polynomial functions are continuous and differentiable on R. So it has to be integrable in (0.1) interval.

Comment: Do you know Rolle's theorem?

Answer (score 7):

As you said, $0=a_1/2+a_2/3+\ldots+a_n/(n+1)=\int_0^1p(x)dx$. If there was no $x$ in $]0,1[$ such that $p(x)=0$ then $p(x)$ would be positive in all the interval $]0,1[$ or negative in all $]0,1[$ (since $p$ is a continuous function), but this would imply that $\int_0^1p(x)dx$ is nonzero, which is a contradiction.